# Is this a gas shutoff valve

Tags: plumbing, natural-gas, shutoff

[image]

We are adding a ceiling in our basement (64 year old house) and can not locate a obvious shutoff valve. They recently removed the meter from within the house and put one outside, and it has a shutout valve beside the meter. I also have noticed shutoff valves farther down the pipe inside (30 feet) in front of the furnace and water heater. I am just curious if this elbow (pictured) and the nubby on the side is a shutoff valve and if i should create an access port for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's not a valve. It looks like a drain, as might be useful if the fitting had been installed in a fire sprinkler or steam line, or functionally just an odd-ball tee fitting.

Comment: I hadn’t considered that the pipes might have also been used for water. Drain seems accurate

Comment: Gas line can also have a "drip leg" , a downward bling leg that debris could drop into. I have incorporated them into gas lines.

Comment: Sediment/condensate trap drain plug...

Comment: This nub is lateral and flows sideways with the pipe and not downwards